# Add text to a figure in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add some text to a 3D wireframe plot. I am starting with the code from [this example](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/mplot3d/wire3d.html) in the matplotlib gallery. From the `Axes` documentation I found a [`text()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.text.html). If I'm reading this correctly, there are 4 required positional arguments (including `self`). I modified the example as follows:

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Grab some test data.
X, Y, Z = axes3d.get_test_data(0.05)

# Plot a basic wireframe.
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z, rstride=10, cstride=10)
ax.text(0, 0, "I'm here")
plt.show()
```

When I run this code, I get

> TypeError: text() missing 1 required positional argument: 's'

How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You have a 3D plot. So you need 3 coordinates, not 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you're not dealing with an [`Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/axes_api.html#the-axes-class) object, but rather an [`Axes3D`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html) object. So you need to provide three coordinate numbers to its [`text()`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.text) method instead of just 2.

Alternatively you could also use the [`text2D()`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.text2D) method, which does require only two coordinate number input arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This leads me to believe that what I'm trying to do isn't quite what I want. I found that `fig.text()` will work better for what I need.

Answer (score 1):

`help(ax.text)` gives the correct documentation:

```
Help on method text in module mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d:

text(x, y, z, s, zdir=None, **kwargs) method of matplotlib.axes._subplots.Axes3DSubplot instance
...
```

So you need 3 positional coordinates, and no `self`.

Comment: Why doesn't help show `self` as one of the arguments?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice The [`self`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-word-self-in-python) object is always passed automatically by python.

Comment: @Xukrao Exactly. In code, we explicitly list it as a parameter. This is why I'm asking why it doesn't appear in the help here? Perhaps it just assumes that the reader knows it is passed in.